# Instagram api - get all photos by hashtag

Tags: api, instagram

I am new to this Instagram API, and I read their doc about endpoints, this is the endpoint that I am using:

```
/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

It is fetching the images, but, only on my accounts photos. I want is, I will give an tag-name, and it wll display all, not just the photos on my account, but all the photos in Instagram too.

Answer (score 12):

I know has been a long time, but just for the record.

Since you need the `public_scope` permission for this (the permission that gives you access to all public data on instagram, and not only your account) you need your app to be reviewed and approved by Instagram. However, if you're using the API for a one-site personal project, Instagram will not approve it.

Here's from Instagram's docs:

> 1: Which use case best describes your Instagram integration?
>
> R: I want to display hashtag content and public content on my website.
>
> A: This use case is not supported. We do not approve the
>   public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying
>   hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you
>   can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers
>   this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display).
>
> You can find more information in the Permission Review documentation.

Comment: A link to the source of this could be very useful

Answer (score 2):

Your client is in Sandbox Mode and can only search for tags of photos posted by invited users. You have to login into https://www.instagram.com/developer, edit your client and click on the "GO LIVE" button.

**If the "GO LIVE" button is disabled**, you have get your app reviewed by Instagram first: Click on the Permissions tab and submit for review. (Company Name, Contact Email and Privacy Policy URL are required to start a submission.) Once approved, u will be able to click Go Live.

Comment: Is it really possible to get all global images for a specific tag? I tried to submit the permission for "I want to display hashtag content and public content on my website." on the settings for my app but getting:

"This use case is not supported. We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display)."
Do you know any examples where I can see this in action?

Comment: No, sorry. We gave up on this. Maybe it isnt possible anymore, but I think it was?

Answer (score 1):

By `hashtag` you mean `tags`.
It works for me. Despite I'm using python [client](https://www.instagram.com/developer/libraries/), it should work well when you're developing your own client. Look:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

api =InstagramAPI(client_secret=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
                   access_token=settings.ACCESS_TOKEN)

result = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name='castle')
media = result[0]

for m in media:
    print (m.images)
    print (m.user)
    print (m.tags)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it and it is working for me.

```
/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?client_id={YOUR_CLIENT_ID}
```

My client id is created before "permission review", it is working now and I am trying to submit permission review to Instagram now, hope it will pass.

Comment: There is no need to promote your app. Only a sample code would suffice

Comment: Actually I would like to try his app to see how it worked. However I looked in the edit and found the app but its not working. It only shows one image and cant change to anothers.

Comment: @nilsi, due to Instagram API policy is changed, my client id can not be used. :(

Comment: You have to use an `access_token` now.

Comment: 'https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=http://localhost/&response_type=token'