# How to get all images by hashtag using instagram API?

Tags: python, json, api, instagram, urllib

I am trying to get all images using specific hashtag e.g. egipt. My query is

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/egipt/media/recent?access_token={access.token}](https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/egipt/media/recent?access_token=%7Baccess.token%7D)

Different combinations as well.

I am not getting any data or getting empty data or
deprecation_warning "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead".

Is is possible to write simple request and get related data via Instagram API?

Answer (score 0):

Please read a similar post on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734962/instagram-api-get-all-photos-by-hashtag). In order to access any public data, you need to get your app approved by Instagram.

The only thing the query will return before your app is approved is your own photos.